# MongoDB aggregate query extremely slow

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've a MongoDB query here which is running extremely slow without an index but the query fields are too big to index so i'm looking for advice on how to optimise this query or create valid index for it:

```
collection.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        article_id: {
            $nin: read_article_ids
        },
        author_id: {
            $in: liked_authors,
            $nin: disliked_authors
        },
        word_count: {
            $gte: 1000,
            $lte: 10000
        },
        article_sentiment: {
            $elemMatch: {
                sentiments: mood
            }
        }
    }
    }, {
        $sample: {
            size: 4
        }
}])
```

The collection in this case is a collection of articles with article_id, author_id, word_count, and article_sentiment. There is around 1.6 million documents in the collection and a query like this takes upwards of 10 seconds without an index. The box has 56gb of memory and is all around pretty specced out.

The query's function is to retrieve a batch of 4 articles by authors the user likes and that they've not read and that match a given sentiment (The article_sentiment key holds a nested array of key:value pairs)

So is this query incorrect for what i'm trying to achieve? Is there a way to improve it?

EDIT: Here is a sample document for this collection.

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("57f7dd597a1026d326fc02c4"),
"publication_name": "National News Inc",
"author_name": "John Hardwell",
"title": "How Shifting Policy Has Stunted Cultural Growth",
"article_id": "2f0896cd47c9423cb5a309c7277dd90d",
"author_id": "51b7f46f6c0f46f2949608c9ec2624d4",
"word_count": 1202,
"article_sentiment": [{
    "sentiments": "happy",
    "weight": 0.528596282005
}, {
    "sentiments": "serious",
    "weight": 0.569274544716
}, {
    "sentiments": "relaxed",
    "weight": 0.825395524502
}]
}
```

Comment: post your sample document

Comment: Just one suggestion, I guess same author cannot be in both `liked_authors` and `disliked_authors`, so you can remove the `$nin` condition from `author_id`, and seems like you can use an index on `article_id` as it seems like the most distinctive attribute on the document

Comment: @cubbuk I'll give creating a article_id index a go but if i remember i've tried that in the past and it complained about the strings being too long, i'll check if thats the case now. I should have also explained that prior to the query being made the liked_authors bucked thats used as a field is enriched with 20-30 similar authors to the ones actually liked. Because of this there is the potential for disliked_authors overlapping with liked, hence the $in & $nin combo!

Comment: Then I guess better approach would be to remove those disliked authors from liked authors as in the end according this query they won't be part of the result anyway.

Comment: @cubbuk [I am not sure if an index on article_id will improve the query performance](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#query-selectivity)

Comment: @Styvane you might be correct, thanks for the article. @patrickjquinn, since you are trying match the sentiment of an article, I guess it is better to save additional field like `moodOfArticle` which represents the sentiment with highest value and you can improve your performance by filtering on `moodOfArticle` field rather than on an array field.

Comment: First of all, I see no need to fire up the aggregation pipeline at all, as you should be able to achieve the same with collection.find(...).limit(4). Then, try your find separately and check the query execution stats (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/cursor.explain/) - if you cannot do anything with the result, post it here.

Comment: One more afterthought: replace the $elemMatch with a simple { article_sentiment.sentiment : mood }

Comment: @cubbuk This would require re-processing of the data but might make a big difference to the query, i'll give that a shot as a last resort as It'll require a full data dump and a change in some key content addition components!

Comment: @mtj Initially find was being used but due to the way the data is structured its grouped by author and limit(4) on a find query will give me 4 by the same author without doing a separate query to get a count for a rand skip, replacing $elemMatch with  article_sentiment.sentiment : mood seems like the best bet for the moment!

Comment: Still, try the find-part isolated and get the execution stats.

Comment: @mtj Here is a link to the paste bin of the explain http://pastebin.com/tahf0cjM I used a 2 document sample set for each field as an example.

Comment: @patrickjquinn Yep, full collection scan on 1.7 mio objects without use of any index - no wonder that this sucks. Try an index on author_id and see what happens.

Comment: Do you really need a random record?

Comment: @mtj I'll try an index of author_id and give it a go now!

Comment: @SergiuZaharie This is just a find so i can perform an explain, the aggregation at the top uses sample to get a set of random articles that aren't by the same author given the way the data is structured, so if a find was in actual use, it would still need the random in order to skip.